# I have a deserialize Json C# class now i want to fetch information from it

Tags: c#, json

this is my deserialize JSON response C# class

```
    public class Apppage
    {
        public Pagelayout[] pageLayouts { get; set; }
        public string pageName { get; set; }
        public string pageType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pagelayout
    {
        public string layout { get; set; }
        public Pagecontrol[] pageControls { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pagecontrol
    {
        public string __type { get; set; }
        public string controlType { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public int pageID { get; set; }
        public bool visible { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string textColor { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public bool autoSize { get; set; }
        public string labelPosition { get; set; }
        public bool showLabel { get; set; }
    }
```

What i want is to do something like this like i did in javascript

e.g : `PageLayout[0].PageControl[1].pageID`.

Can i do something like this with this C# class.

Comment: Have you tried anything and got error?

Answer (score 0):

On your deserialized object, you should be able to do something very similar, although the naming is slightly different in your C# representation.  Instead of 'PageLayout' you have 'pageLayouts' and instead of 'PageControl' you have 'pageControls'.  Does this work in your case for accessing the PageID?

```
pageLayouts[0].pageControls[1].pageID
```

Answer (score 0):

C# likes names.  Assume you have a List of PageLayout like this...

```
var pages = getPayLayout();
var thePage= pages.Where(p=>p.Layout == "Somevalue").ToList().First();
var pControl = thePage.pageControls.Where(p=>p.pageID == "value").ToList().First();
```